# Spring 3 mvc nested form:select

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc

In my scenario, i'm developing nested select on a JSP, binded to a bean:

**Bean**

```
public class WizardPanelp1Bean {

private Integer id;
private Stringofpanels stringofpanels;
private Paneltype paneltype;
private Integer number;
private String paneltypestring;
//and getters/setters... [Omitted]
```

Now i have the Paneltype object, another simple bean

**Paneltype**

```
private Integer id;
private double peakpower;
private double weight;
private String name;
private double dimension;
private double conversion;
private Set functions = new HashSet(0);
private Set sensors = new HashSet(0);
private Set panels = new HashSet(0);
//[Getters/setters omitted as usual]
```

So, i prepare the view, with a bean named **wb**
a simple arraylist of panels

```
 public class PanelsBean {
    private ArrayList<WizardPanelp1Bean> panels =new ArrayList<WizardPanelp1Bean>();
```

and finally i go to the **jsp** (please note this is in a )

```
<tbody>
         <c:forEach items="${wb.panels}" varStatus="loop" var="item">
            <tr>
                <td>${item.id}</td>
                <td>
                    <form:select  path="panels[${loop.index}].paneltype" >
                        <c:forEach var="type" items="${types}">
                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${item.paneltype.id==type.id}">
                                    <form:option selected="selected" value="${type.id}" label="${type.name}" />
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    <form:option value="${type.id}" label="${type.name}" />
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </form:select>
                </td>
                    <td><form:input style="width:180px" path="panels[${loop.index}].number" /></td>
                    <td>
                    <div>
                        <form:input style="visibility: hidden ; width:0px" path="panels[${loop.index}].id" disabled="disabled" />
                        <a href="javascript:remove(${item.id},${stringofpanels.id})" class="wb.panels.remove" >Rimuovi</a>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>    
     </tbody>
```

every time i get a null reference to paneltype. I obviously used a `@InitBinder` on the controller:
**Initbinder**

```
@InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
            binder.registerCustomEditor(Paneltype.class, "paneltype", new PropertyEditorSupport() {
                @Override
                public void setAsText(String text) {
                    int i=0;
                    PaneltypeDAO pDAO=new PaneltypeDAO();
                    setValue(pDAO.findById(Integer.parseInt(text)));
                }
            });
        }
```

but the code never reach this. It's like the jsp is sure that the value is `null`.

Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: i think i missed the name="" after <form:select  path="panels[${loop.index}].paneltype" > but now i can't bind the result

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem persists when you try to submit this form and not getting the binded values in the model.

Try to initialize your list using **LazyList**. Please replace your panels declaration in PanelsBean class as below.

```
private List<WizardPanelp1Bean> panels = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList<WizardPanelp1Bean>(),FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(WizardPanelp1Bean.class));
```

Hope this helps you. Cheers.